# Why does HttpWorkerRequest fail during HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest after a .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 upgrade?

Tags: .net, httpruntime

I am upgrading our application, which has an internal webserver, from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0.

I am handling a request with an object `HttpListenerWorkerRequest`, that extends the `HttpWorkerRequest` class, and creates a request which `GetRawUrl()` returns a Url in the format of `http://localhost:82/Default.aspx`.

In .NET 2.0, sending this to `HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(httpListenerWorkerRequest)` works without issue, however in .NET 4.0, I get a web page with the nothing but the text "Bad Request" on it.

Cracking open `HttpRuntime`, I can see that Bad Requests are thrown from `ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)`, a private method that tries to build an HttpContext.

I tried this myself:

```
try
{
    //what's going on?
    hcontext = new HttpContext(workerRequest);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Debugging break point here
}
```

Pre-update (.NET 2.0), it builds fine, post-update (.NET 4.0), I get a System.ArgumentException stating that

`The relative virtual path 'http:/localhost:82/Default.aspx' is not allowed here`,  thrown at

```
at System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_ClientFilePath()
   at System.Web.Security.CookielessHelperClass.RemoveCookielessValuesFromPath()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.Init(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.HttpContext..ctor(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at Talcasoft.Web.Hosting.HttpWorkerThread.Run(Object request) in      
   C:\[OurLibrary].Web\Hosting\HttpWorkerThread.cs:line 51
```

What has changed in .NET to cause this, and what can I do to get around it?

**EDIT** I have just noticed that the disallowed http: is followed by a single slash, not a double, although the GetRawUrl() in the request certainly returns a double.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes I think you hit the XSS change

Comment: @Lex Li, thanks for that, it certainly looks possible. I'll have to test that tomorrow, but let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Lex Li, not the case, unfortunately, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Can you show the entire exception? Set your debugger the break on all exceptions and disable "my code only" so that the debugger pauses on the first exception (the one that is being caught in ProcessRequestInternal).

Comment: That doesn't look like a relative virtual path at all.

Comment: @usr Amended the question to include it's a System.ArgumentException at VirtualPath.Create (I can see this is getting called within ProcessRequestInternal). Is that the information you were requesting?

Comment: @Andreas I agree. I didn't write the server code, but the person who did has left. It works in 2.0, so I am loathe to touch it until I understand how it broke. Stepping through it in 2.0 shows that nothing appears to have changed in the WorkerRequest

Comment: Did you make any progress yet? I'm interested in whether my suggestions works for you.

Comment: @usr We had to take our kid to the doctor today, do my mind has been on other things. I'll let you know tomorrow. Thanks for the input

Comment: usr and @NSGaga You are both worthy of receiving the bounty points, however, unless you know of some way to split the points, I have to choose. I thank you both enormously, but have decided, as NSGaga supplied the actual line of code I used to fix the problem (and he/she could use the additional rep more than usr) I will mark NSGaga as the accepted answer IF you work your last two comments into the post

Comment: @usr Please see comment above. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a 100% certain that this is the 'exact answer' but looks pretty close to me - and there is some more to write...

There seems to be a `breaking change` of a sort inside the `VirtualPath` class - and it's substantiated with how they are checking for `illegal characters`. (btw. you can google the 'VirtualPath source' for what seems a .NET 4 version of it).

Inside `VirtualPath.Create` a check is invoked for 'illegal virtual path characters'.

It first goes into registry ("**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET**", "**VerificationCompatibility**") - to see if the `compatibility` mode 'illegal chars' should be used.

> Based on that - I'm guessing (I don't have a way of checking this
>   right now) - that **if you set the above registry value (int) to `1`** -
>   **you should get your methods working `the old way`** and w/o any
>   additional effort. Note: a IIS (or host process) **restart may be required** as suggested in one of the links

And then based on that registry flag it used either of these two...

```
':', '?', '*', '\0' // .NET 4.0 - the default
'\0' // the 'compatibility' mode
```

That seems to actually describe your story quite well as your path with the 'port' designation is actually `illegal` per the new default.

---

#### FINAL EDIT / EXPLANATION:

**(update based on comments and the solution that solved it)**
This is my understanding of what's going on inside:

1) Solution for prior to .NET 4.0 was the `VerificationCompatibility` key (see above).

2) With .NET 4.0 internal handling and fixing of url paths is made more robust. And works fine in most cases. In short, **all paths are fixed and normalized before entering** the `VirtualPath.Create` - and your `http://...` becomes an expected absolute path `/Default.aspx`.

However when you supply the `HttpWorkerRequest` (instead of Request/Response etc.) - the `raw Url` is taken directly from the `worker` - **and the responsibility for supplying the correct and normalized paths is down to your worker request**. (this is still a bit iffy, and looks like a bug or bad handling internally).

**To reproduce the issue:**

```
internal class MyRequest : SimpleWorkerRequest
{
    public MyRequest() : base("", "", String.Empty, String.Empty, null) { }
    public override String GetRawUrl() { return "http://localhost:82/Default.aspx"; }
}
// ...
var wr = new MyRequest();
var context1 = new HttpContext(wr);
```

Gives the error `The relative virtual path 'http:/localhost:82/Default.aspx' is not allowed here.`

**The FIX:**

```
public override String GetRawUrl() 
{ return new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsolutePath; }
```

---

And some of the research on the subject based on that `VerificationCompatibility` keyword in the registry which seems to be the key to it.

[Ampersand in URL filename = bad request](http://forums.asp.net/t/1371764.aspx/2/10)

[Configure IIS to accept URL with Special Characters...](http://adorr.net/2010/01/configure-iis-to-accept-url-with-special-characters.html)

[For 32 vs 64 difference in Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543850/bad-request-error-400-on-iis7-net-3-5/3545091#3545091)

And here is a similar thing from Microsoft - but what seems to be a 'hotfix' for '2.0', i.e. doesn't apply to you - but just attaching it as something official in this line.

[FIX: "HTTP 400 - Bad request" error message in the .NET Framework 1.1](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437)
[FIX: Error message when you try to visit an ASP.NET 2.0-based Web page: "HttpException (0x80004005): '/HandlerTest/WebForm1.aspx/a:b' is not a valid virtual path"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932552)
[ASP.NET 2.0 x64 – You may get HTTP 400 Bad Request or Error as mentioned in KB 932552 or 826437](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-2-0-x64-you-may-get-http-400-bad-request-or-error-as-mentioned-in-kb-932552-or-826437.aspx)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET
>
> DWord Value Name: VerificationCompatibility  Value Data: 1

Comment: It looks like the right answer, but still doesn't work. I'm going to drill down a bit further on this idea before I give up on it though. BTW, I'm using dotPeek to reflect on the code. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: I tried fast and it's not easy to reproduce (context, request). But if you use a custom `HttpWorkerRequest` and just override `GetRawUrl()` to return your url - it fails (and this being the culprit `VirtualPath.Create("...", VirtualPathOptions.AllowAbsolutePath)` - called internally and you have no 'say' there). The registry setting indeed doesn't seem to have any effect on that so I confirmed that. **I think it's down to your `HttpListenerWorkerRequest.GetRawUrl()` which needs to return the proper absolute path (w/o host:port)**.

Comment: i.e. something like... `public override String GetRawUrl() { return new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsolutePath; }` in your `HttpListenerWorkerRequest` - should `fix` the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. I had to take the day off, so I'll have a look at your work tomorrow.

Comment: the line public override String GetRawUrl() { return new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsolutePath; } worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your time on this!

Comment: you're welcome John - glad it helped. I just made a final edit to incorporate what's in the comments here. I think that's pretty much the whole story. I don't want to make your life more complicated, just to wrap this up into a proper answer. Whatever you do is fine, Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it. It still contains some guesswork but I'll include a test that you can make to prove or disprove this hypothesis.

The stack trace shows `ClientFilePath.get` as the origin of the exception. It looks like this:

```
    if (this._clientFilePath == null)
    {
        string rawUrl = this.RawUrl;
        int index = rawUrl.IndexOf('?');
        if (index > -1)
        {
            rawUrl = rawUrl.Substring(0, index);
        }
        this._clientFilePath
     = VirtualPath.Create(rawUrl, VirtualPathOptions.AllowAbsolutePath); //here!
    }
    return this._clientFilePath;
```

It creates a `VirtualPath` and allows only absolute values. `http://localhost:82/Default.aspx` is a relative path because it does not start with a slash. It is *not* a URL in this context because it is not being interpreted as such.

So `VirtualPath.Create` understandably denies this path. I don't know why .NET 2.0 allowed this, but .NET 4.0 requires an absolute path and according to the code this is non-configurable.

Actually, I have never seen `HttpRequest.RawUrl` return a URL before. In my experience it should return an absolute path like `/Default.aspx`. If you want to set the host and port you have to find other means to do that.

So the fix is to not use `http://localhost:82/Default.aspx` but `/Default.aspx`. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that tomorrow, I was off today

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks so much for your time and help on this. Unfortunately as there are 2 of you supplying this answer, I'm a bit stumped as to who to accept as the bounty winner.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer which explains the problem most clearly and which will be most useful for future visitors who have this exact problem. I'll leave that for you to judge.